# how to accept only 1 forward slash in htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a regex RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$           index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and I can access the URL like this:

- `/en/` (expected result)
- `/en//////////////`  (I don't want to match this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) matches against has already had multiple slashes reduced to single slashes. So when you request `/en//////////////`, you are also matching against `/en/`, so the *pattern* is successful.

To specifically match `/en/` only and not `/en//////////////` you can try matching against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in a preceding *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]+/$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here, the *condition* is simply used as a second level of validation, since the `REQUEST_URI` server variable has not had multiple slashes reduced.

Or, match against `THE_REQUEST` (the first line of the HTTP request headers), for example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[a-z]+/(\?|\s)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that `THE_REQUEST` would also contain the query string (and request method), hence the slightly more verbose regex. eg. `GET /en/ HTTP/1.1`

Although, you could instead redirect (correct) URLs that end in (or contain) multiple slashes to the single slashed (canonical) URL. This would be a separate rule *before* your existing rule:

```
# Canonical redirect - reduce multiple slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This reduces multiple slashes anywhere in the URL-path part of the URL, issuing a 301 (permanent) redirect to the canonical URL that contains single slashes.

**UPDATE:** The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `(.*)` captures the URL-path with any multiple slashes reduced to single slashes (this is used later in the *substitution* string). The preceding *condition* with the regex `\s[^?]*//` checks to see if there are any occurrences of a double slash in the requested URL-path only, ie. before any `?` (that would otherwise signify the start of the query string). We need to avoid matching any double slashes that might appear in the query string.

Comment: thanks, can you also explain what this part means: \s[^?]*//

Comment: @user_unknown That regex checks for any double slashes in the requested URL-path only. The `[^?]*` part matches anything _except_ a literal `?` (that would denote the start of a query string), since we need to avoid matching a double slash that might occur in the query string. I've updated my answer.